# Set up for matrix solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

I've haven't touched linear algebra in a while so I'm sorry if this seems simple but I did a google search and I am still confused.

I have to find a solution to the following set of equations:

```
6=a(d+x)
15=b(a+y)
24=c(b+x)
10=d(c+y)
1=xy
```

I figured I have 1 more unknown than equations so I should have a degree of freedom. So I choose x=1, then it's obvious that y=1 and my problem reduces to.

```
6=a+ad
15=b+ba
24=c+cb
10=d+dc
```

I feel like I should be able to solve this using some software to do an inverse matrix and multiply

```
y=A*x
Inv(A)*y=x
```

but I'm not sure how to set up my matrix and feeling like I am tacking this problem in the wrong way. should this be solved numerically?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set this up as a linear system, because it is nonlinear:  some of the unknowns are multiplied together. There is no recipe, apart from numerical, for solving general systems of nonlinear equations. If you just want one solution (not all of them), then choosing $x=1$ and obtaining $y=1$, as you did, is a good move. But I would not multiply out the rest. Instead, keep the products as they are: 
\begin{split} 
6&=a(d+1)\\
15&=b(a+1)\\
24&=c(b+1) \\ 
10 &= d(c+1) 
\end{split}
With all those composite integers with small divisors, this  smells  like a puzzle. So I try a puzzle-oriented approach: assume $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers. From the second equation, $b$ is odd and $a$ is even. From the first, $a=2$ and $d=2$. Then $b=5$ and $c=4$ are easily found.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. I did end up just solving it using pen and paper similar to how you explained but I just felt like there should have been something more clever especially when the variables don't work out to be nice integers like in this example... I guess there isn't